# Access node only from manual URL

Tags: 7, users

Looking for a module or hint to allow a node only be accessed from the manually set URL.

Ex. having node 42 with  `URL path setting = myStory` can only be accesed with `http://host/myStory`, while `http://host/node/42` will return a `NOT FOUND`.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you have a rethink about your strategy here - "security through obscurity", which I'm certain is what you're attempting to accomplish, is a waste of time. Besides, your users will always be forwarded to the alias anyway. And whether or not the alias is the same you'll still find canonical and shortlink meta tags with the old node/ path, unless you alter all that as well. It's not worth the effort

Comment: @Clive It is not for security. I want to e-mail to users a link so they can (temporary) read the node without to login or be a authent user. Simple avoid that someone can loop thru all node numbers to get the content.

Comment: Yep I understand that, that's called security through obscurity - you're trying to stop people finding other content based on a URL, not based on proper authentication. Suffice to say this is not a simple job (as well as being very bad practice, but that's your call obviously). There are a few hypothetical solutions but they all involve multiple steps and probably some patches to core. I would genuinely consider changing your approach, this will take a long time, cause you a lot of headaches, and won't actually solve the problem you're looking to solve

Comment: @Clive propably you are right for the trouble to get when trying to get this working with Drupal. But I cannot follow your concerns about security. What is the diference to transfer a *secret key* in a request URL from transfering a *session cookie* in the request header or coded in the URL. Common *HTTP session* handling **is** security by obscurity. My *secret* nodes won't be listed in any public view.

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree, this isn't the right place for a debate...

Answer (score 1):

With respect to all of the commentary given to the question, if you really want to do this, you can look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in any number of places and based upon its content, do things differently.

For example, if you go to:

```
www.example.com/path/to/hidden/content

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will be /path/to/hidden/content
```

yet if you go to

```
www.example.com/node/###

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will be /node/###
```

but the same content will be displayed while the url in the browser will be different.

So, if you want to obfuscate your nodes based up that, you could delete their content in a preprocess hook, or cobble together something in hook_init to do a 404 but just also be very wary of the caching of pages for anonymous users as well, so hook_boot would be needed instead, and do you want to do this for logged in users and any of numerous other what ifs.........

Plus, if you have global redirect or another similar module installed, the above won't work as it will have already redirected you to the alias.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for the [Rabbit Hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module.

> Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx

And from options:

> Deliver a page not found page.

Comment: That will give a 404 for the alias as well